# CSS animate scale

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to animate scale from .5 - 1.
When the div is first added I add css to scale it to .5 then I have on the element css to scale it back to 1.

```
     $('.item').each(function(count){
        $(this).css({top: 0, left:20, transform : "scale(.5)"});
    });
```

CSS

```
.item {
  -webkit-transition: top 0.4s ease-out 0s, left 0.4s ease-out 0s, right 0.4s ease-out 0s;
     -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, left 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, right 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
       -o-transition: top 0.4s ease-out 0s, left 0.4s ease-out 0s, right 0.4s ease-out 0s;
      -ms-transition: top 0.4s ease-out 0s, left 0.4s ease-out 0s, right 0.4s ease-out 0s;
          transition: top 0.4s ease-out 0s, left 0.4s ease-out 0s, right 0.4s ease-out 0s;

  transform: scale(1) ease-in-out 0s;   
  -moz-transform: scale(1) ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Why would this not work. it stays at .5 and does not animate to 1

This style does not animate either.

```
-moz-transform: scale(.4) 2s ease-in-out 4s;
```

I'm using firefox shouldn't that work. or am I writing it incorrect as shorthand

Comment: the scale attribute in css is not supported in all browsers, try a jquery like: `$('.item').animate({width: '100%', height:'100%});` but it depends on what you are re-sizing.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I don't think that setting the transform via the jquery css function will apply the browser-specific styles (-webkit,-moz-,-o,-ms), which means they probably won't work on most browsers today.

Second, setting a style with JS via the `style` attribute on the element is known as an `inline style` and overrides any css classes/selectors. I don't think that's causing a problem here.

What you need are 2 classes. One that already has a scale of .5, and then apply the second class with JS when it loads. The other way would be to use CSS Keyframes. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_keyframes.asp